# filter Java collection in lambda w/o creating new one

Tags: lambda, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I have a final ConcurrentMap in Java and want to filter it's elements without creating a new one.

Question is: can I reference collection (**people**) from inside the lambda?

```
final ConcurrentMap<String, String> people = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
people.put("Sam", "developer");
people.put("Kate", "tester");

people.forEach((name, role) -> {
    if (name.length() > 3)
        people.remove(name);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.keySet()`, `.values()`, and `.entrySet()` return live views of a map's keys, values and entries respectively.  You can remove elements from those collections and the corresponding entries will be removed from the map:

```
people.keySet().removeIf(name -> name.length() > 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

This has sort of been discussed just recently, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306005/non-interference-requirement-on-java-8-streams/).

The documentation states that `CHM` provide *weakly consistent traversal*, as opposed to *fail-fast traversal*; as seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#Weakly) What this means:

> they **may** proceed concurrently with other operations
>
> they are guaranteed to traverse elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and **may (but are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction**.

Generally `CHM` operations that change it's structure are thread-safe, but what you want to achieve is still discouraged by the Stream documentation. This is called *interference* and should be avoided. If you change that structure with an simple `HashMap` you will get `ConcurrentModificationException` since you are modifying the source while traversing it. Unless you have a compelling reason not to discard your previous map, you should just filter the values you are interested in and collect those.

You can also see how you can get un-expected results when you *add* to a `CMH` from the link above.