# Merge the iterator collection after remove method is called. How the change is reflected in main collection?

Tags: java, collections

I went through many pages on the web to understand the working of `ConcurrentHashMap` and how it clones the actual map to iterate. This manages to get the Weakly Consistent property.

Now, while iterating if I call the `remove()` method, then at what stage is this change reflected in the main collection?

Basically, want to understand how the clone and main collection are merged?

Is it done once the iteration is complete?

Answer (score 0):

First, `ConcurrentHashMap` don't make copy to iterate, see `ConcurrentHashMap#entrySet`.

Second, the change of `remove` reflect to the collection immediately, see `ConcurrentHashMap#BaseIterator#remove`.

Comment: the question here is *when* do you see the updates that happened because of remove

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that `ConcurrentHashMap` uses buckets, like any other hash-based structure. When you lookup (`remove`) an entry, it uses the hashCode to find that *bucket* where the entry might reside first and then remove it immediately.

The question is, will you be able to spot/see this removal that actually happened; for example you iterate and print the contents of `CHM` and remove some of the entries at the same time. If you already "visited" some bucket via `forEach` for example (and traversal happens on bucket-to-bucket basis), and the entry was removed from that bucket - you will not spot it.

On the other hand if you will remove and entry from a "yet to be visited" bucket - you will spot the removal.

That is for example the reason that `size` returns a "at the moment" known size - it counts for example entries from bucketA, then later someone remove some of those entries, `CHM` will not get back or synchronize to count those again.

Also some very good comments to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306005/non-interference-requirement-on-java-8-streams)