# Example of non-interference in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837415/non-interference-exact-meaning-in-java-8-streams), we can modify the source and it's not called interference:

> you can modify the stream elements themselves and it should not be called as "interference".

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306005/non-interference-requirement-on-java-8-streams), the code

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add("test");
  list.forEach(x -> list.add(x));
```

will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

But my code,

```
Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
                new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos"),
                new Employee(2, "Bill Gates"),
                new Employee(3, "hendry cavilg"),
                new Employee(4, "mark cuban"),
                new Employee(5, "zoe"),
                new Employee(6, "billl clinton"),
                new Employee(7, "ariana") ,
                new Employee(8, "cathre"),
                new Employee(9, "hostile"),
                new Employee(10, "verner"),
            };
        Employee el=new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos");
        List<Employee> li=Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps);
        li.stream().map(s->{s.setName("newname");return s;}).forEach(System.out::print);
```

doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, even though it in fact changes the source.

And this code,

```
Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
                new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos"),
                new Employee(2, "Bill Gates"),
                new Employee(3, "hendry cavilg"),
                new Employee(4, "mark cuban"),
                new Employee(5, "zoe"),
                new Employee(6, "billl clinton"),
                new Employee(7, "ariana") ,
                new Employee(8, "cathre"),
                new Employee(9, "hostile"),
                new Employee(10, "verner"),
            };
        Employee el=new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos");
        List<Employee> li=Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps);
        li.stream().map(s->{s.setName("newname");li.add(s);return s;}).limit(10).forEach(System.out::print);
```

throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at java8.Streams.lambda$0(Streams.java:33)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
```

So, I don't exactly understand what type of modifications are allowed to the source and what are not. It would be very helpful to see an example which interferes and have a stateful and side-effect producing stream, with proper indication that which is which.

Comment: whoa! lot of answers already. can someone post an example code which contains statefull, interfering,side-effect behavior to get accepted ans answer.please !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do this:

`li.stream().map(s->{s.setName("newname");return s;})`

**you didn't alter the list itself but an element within this list**; so it doesn't trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException` as you expected.

In the last code snippet, you are using `Array.asList`.
You have to know that `Array.asList` returns a mere **read-only wrapper** over an array (a specific **inner ArrayList** class) explaining why `add` is not supported.

Indeed this inner class does not override **AbstractList#add** method by design; causing `UnsupportedOperationException`; and still not `ConcurrentModificationException` as you expected again.

Here's an example similar to your last snippet that does throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee[] arrayOfEmps = {
      new Employee(1, "Jeff Bezos")
    };
    Employee el = new Employee(11, "Bill Gates");
    List<Employee> li = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps)); // to avoid read-only restriction
    li.stream().peek(s -> li.add(el)).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Note that I'm wrapping the `Arrays.List` return with a "true" `ArrayList`, allowing writing because this one implements the `add` method ;)

Comment: this is also called a non-structural modification

Answer (score 5):

Your first example changes the existing elements of the `Stream`, but doesn't add or remove elements from the source. Therefore it's not an interference.

Your second example attempts to do interference, by adding an element to the source during the `Stream` pipeline. However, you get `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of `ConcurrentModificationException`, since you try to add elements to a fixed sized `List` (which is returned by `Arrays.asList`).

Change your second example to:

```
List<Employee> li=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayOfEmps));
li.stream().map(s->{s.setName("newname");li.add(s);return s;}).limit(10).forEach(System.out::print);
```

and you should get `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a *structural* on *non-structural* change of the source of the `Stream`. For example `ArrayList` doc says:

> merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification...

So in your example this means that changing `Employee` per-se, does not changes the `List` itself (does not remove or add an element). But changing the `List` itself, will fail with a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

list.stream().forEach(x -> list.remove(x));
```

But there are sources where interference is more than OK, called *weakly consistent traversal*, like `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
 ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> chm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
 chm.put(1, "one");
 chm.put(2, "two");
 chm.put(3, "three");

 chm.entrySet().stream()
         .forEach(x -> chm.remove(x.getKey()));
```

This will not fail with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the size of the list you are working on.

In the first example you are changing a value of the Employee object inside of your list.

In the second you are adding an item in your list.

That's the difference!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is modifying the stream element, not the list itself:

`s->{s.setName("newname")` changes a field name in the element of the stream, this doesn't interfere with the stream or its source.

The `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` is also unrelated, it's caused by the fact that you attempt to call `add` on a fixed-size list (which is the result of `Arrays.asList`).
Any time one calls `add`, `remove`, etc. on the result of `Arrays.asList`, the unsupported operation exception is raised, as the collect is fixed in size.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example does **not** modify the initial list.

A stream is just a *view* on the list, therefore the *initial* list is **not at all** affected by your stream code.

Whereas the second example makes explicit use of `list.add()`.

That is all there is to this.